# Multiple toggle buttons android issue

Tags: android

i am making an app for controlling 8 relays. Point is i am new to programming and code shows all type of errors while using more than 2 toggle buttons.I hope below will send desired command to my arduino when toggle is on/off. but how do i use if/else when there are many toggles(say in my case 4 toggle) and i also need to last states when i close the app or use app in other device. guess its a lot to ask.

```
toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
            commandArduino("  ");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            commandArduino("  ");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Whats your problem??Are the toggle buttons are not working??

Comment: I am able to use the conditions for one toggle, but what if there are many toggles...please bear with me as i am new to it. this must be lame to ask.toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
            commandArduino("  ");
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            commandArduino("  ");
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});

Comment: @BharatKumar..I will fully try to help you...But i am not getting that what you actually want...Are you want to perform different action on each toggle click??

Comment: Please edit the question again...I am not getting it in the comment only

Comment: Please give me some time...I will soon update you about it

Comment: yes all different actions for on/off states of all toggles

Comment: @BharatKumar...Did my solution helpful for you??

Comment: hi ravindra ... i am checking

Comment: ok Bharat..Please let me know if there is any concern

Comment: i am getting the uncheck msg but not the checked

Comment: ok...Let me try once angain...Soon i will update you about it

Comment: thanks got it working after setting true condition first and then false....marking it as working ....thanks a lot...you were of great help

Comment: @BharatKumar....I have update the code..please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Please find the below solution..It will workable for you***

```
public class Example extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ToggleButton button2;
private ToggleButton button1;
private ToggleButton button3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example);
    button1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    button2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    button3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton3);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.toggleButton1:
        if(button1.isChecked())
        {
            button1.setChecked(true);

            Toast.makeText(Example.this, "BUTTON1 UNCHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            button1.setChecked(false);
            Toast.makeText(Example.this, "BUTTON1 CHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



        break;
    case R.id.toggleButton2:
        if(button2.isChecked())
        {
            button2.setChecked(true);
            Toast.makeText(Example.this, "BUTTON2 UNCHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            button2.setChecked(false);
            Toast.makeText(Example.this, "BUTTON2 CHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        break;
    case R.id.togglebutton3:
        if(button3.isChecked())
        {
            button3.setChecked(true);
            Toast.makeText(Example.this, "BUTTON3 UNCHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            button3.setChecked(false);
            Toast.makeText(Example.this, "BUTTON3 CHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
   }
 }
```