# change color of my ToggleButton when clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, togglebutton

I have some toggle buttons that represent the days in the week.

When a user clicks on a `ToggleButton` i want it to switch states and change color, indicating to the user that it was been clicked.

This is what one of my `ToggleButton`s looks like:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton_monday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:textOff="MON"
    android:textOn="MON"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/toggleButton_tuesday"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />
```

[image]

I want the button to look like this after it's clicked (i want the same border and shape, but just different color and state changed):

[image]

---

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978880/how-to-change-color-of-the-toggle-button) doesn't work, as i already have an `android:background` for my toggle buttons to show the custom border around the button.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253512/change-on-color-of-a-switch) doesn't work, as i am using a `ToggleButton` and not a `SwitchCompat`

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the current `android:background` i am setting my `ToggleButton`s with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="75dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#878787"
        />
</shape>
```

---

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Thank you @Broken and @Moustafa Shahin, i used a combination of their answers.

First i created two resource files for my ToggleButtons `toggle_button_default.xml` and `toggle_button_checked.xml` (check code above in the first EDIT). Basically, the background colors are just different in the two XMLs.

Second, i created a seletor called `toggle_button_state.xml`, and loaded the appropriate resources files, that i created above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- WHEN IS CHECKED -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_default" android:state_checked="false" />

    <!-- WHEN IS NOT CHECKED -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_checked" android:state_checked="true" />

</selector>
```

And lastly, for my ToggleButtons, i set the `toggle_button_state` as the background for them:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton_monday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_button_state"
    android:textOff="MON"
    android:textOn="MON"/>
```

In the Activity, i have an `onClick` method, that i can use to monitor the clicks:

```
class RentActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id){
            R.id.toggleButton_monday ->{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Monday Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return
            }
     ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create new file in `drawable` directory with list of states.

You can name it `toggle_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- WHEN IS CHECKED -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="false" />

    <!-- WHEN IS NOT CHECKED -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true" />

</selector>
```

Above file you can use as `background` of `ToggleButton`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton_monday"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_background"
        android:textOff="ON"
        android:textOn="OFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

By default button has grey border. When would you like to remove it just add:

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

to your `ToggleButton` in xml file.

You can also add `OnCheckedChangeListener`. If you have many buttons you can add all of them to the list, and in loop add that same listener for all of them:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<ToggleButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Add ToggleButtons to list
        listOfButtons.add(findViewById(R.id.toggleButton_monday));

        // Create listener for all of them
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = (buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            // Do something
        };


        // Add listener to all od buttons
        for (ToggleButton button : listOfButtons) {
            button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but i currently already have a background that gives my buttons a border. I would lose my border if i used this method

Comment: oh actually, after looking at your code again, in `toggle_background.xml`, can i just use 2 different resource files in `<item android:drawable=` ?

Comment: Yes, you are using `state_checked="false"` when button is **NOT** checked.

And `state_checked="true"` when button is checked.

Comment: @Barcode when would you like to remove grey border just add:
`style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`

Answer (score 2):

you can create 2 background resource files and change them depends on status :

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        // The toggle is enabled
        //the background resource which mean status is enable
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
        //the background resource which mean status is disabled
    }
}
```

});

Comment: hm i'll give that a try, but is there a better way to do this, since i have 7 toggle buttons. So calling `setOnCheckedChangeListener` 7 times seems kind of a lot

Comment: you can add onclick function with switch case to get clicke toggle id to them and try this solution if you do not  want to create listener like this ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30542959/8068914)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an elegant way to do this, you might want to try using a GridView....

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="24dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    />
```

...which will allow you to populate your layout with items in a way that lets you iterate through them more easily. You can create a custom Adapter and assign it to the gridview:

```
GridView gridview = findViewById(R.id.gridview);
MyCustomAdapter _Adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext());
gridview.setAdapter(_Adapter);
```

Which will allow you to set a single onClickListener for all your buttons in one place:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
        _Adapter.toggleItem(position);
    });
```

You can find an in depth tutorial on creating a custom gridview adapter [here](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/)